# Staging Many Lightweight Cisco AP's for Deployment

Tags: cisco, wireless, capwap

My organization is soon going to be deploying approximately 600 new Cisco 2602i access points in a CAPWAP deployment with several 5508 controllers.

This is an infrastructure refresh; currently we have a mix of older Cisco AP's using CAPWAP with several sets of WiSM controllers.   Our current procedure for deploying new/replacement AP's is, to my understanding, the standard priming procedure as listed in [this Cisco Support Forum document](https://supportforums.cisco.com/docs/DOC-1540).

- Connect new access point to the network at our desks
- AP gets a DHCP address
- DHCP Option 43 points AP to a controller
- Log into NCS Prime and find the new AP
- Change AP name and Primary/Secondary controller
- Box AP back up and take to site for deployment

I know there are other options for initially getting the AP to talk to a controller, such as [Over-the-Air-Provisioning](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/ps6366/products_tech_note09186a008093d74a.shtml) or placing the AP into a Layer 2 VLAN with a controller.  But these seem focused on just getting the AP connected to ANY controller, not priming it for a specific Primary/Secondary controller.

I would like to setup some sort of staging/prep area for pre-configuring the new access points, conducting inventory, tagging with asset tags, sorting AP by final deployment area, and so on.

In setting up this staging area, is there a better way to prime these AP's quickly and easily?  Or are we already doing this in the most efficient manner?

Comment: Do you know a scripting language?

Comment: @MikePennington Yeah, but I'm no guru. Perl mostly with some ancient knowledge in Expect/TCL.

Comment: It has a console port... I would assume you could configure one for deployment without it ever connecting to the network. (copy and edit the config from one that's been setup)

Comment: @RickyBeam I believe you can't set any settings on a Lightweight AP via the Console port.  See [this Cisco Doc](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/wireless/controller/7.0/configuration/guide/c70lwap.html#wp1345331).   It states "After you convert an access point to lightweight mode, the console port provides read-only access to the unit. "   It could be wrong, or I could be mis-remembering.  It has been a long time since I've tried to Console into one of the Lightweight AP's.  I'll fire an AP up and test later today.

Comment: That is correct, you're unable to configure it through the console port in lightweight mode. You can enable some hidden commands but it isn't supported.

Comment: "Access points converted to lightweight mode must get an IP address and discover the controller using DHCP, DNS, or IP subnet broadcast." read: it doesn't have a local config in LW mode.

Comment: @RickyBeam that is correct, I will look at revising the wording above as I was not entirely clear in asking my question.  The specific settings to "prime" a lightweight AP are done on the Wireless Controller.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I would like to setup some sort of staging/prep area for pre-configuring the new access points, conducting inventory, tagging with asset tags, sorting AP by final deployment area, and so on.
>
> In setting up this staging area, is there a better way to prime these AP's quickly and easily? Or are we already doing this in the most efficient manner?

*NOTE: I am assuming you're already familiar with loading MIBs on a Windows / Linux machine, and using `snmpwalk` / `snmpset`... if not, please let me know*

I recently discovered how well you can manage Cisco's LWAPs through the [AIRESPACE-WIRELESS-MIB](http://tools.cisco.com/Support/SNMP/do/BrowseMIB.do?local=en&step=2&mibName=AIRESPACE-WIRELESS-MIB), in fact I have mostly forsaken our WCS in favor of managing our LWAPs with the MIB (we have a couple hundred LWAPs spread across multiple WLCs at our facility).

Since you know Perl, you could write a loop to poll your WLCs for the new LWAPs; then the script reacts accordingly when it sees a new LWAP mac-address on a WLC.

- Loop through a list of all controllers, then poll the LWAPs on each controller with [bsnAPEthernetMacAddress (ro)](http://tools.cisco.com/Support/SNMP/do/BrowseOID.do?local=en&translate=Translate&objectInput=1.3.6.1.4.1.14179.2.2.1.1.33#oidContent).  Use the mac-address as the unique identifying key for all activity on this LWAP.
- When you see a new LWAP, print the discovery time / mac-address of the LWAP; then ask the user what hostname / location to assign to this LWAP
- Optionally perform [bsnAPClearConfig (rw)](http://tools.cisco.com/Support/SNMP/do/BrowseOID.do?local=en&translate=Translate&objectInput=1.3.6.1.4.1.14179.2.2.1.1.18#oidContent) using `snmpset` (note 255.254.253.252.251.250 is the hexidecimal index to `bsnAPTable` translated into decimal octets); setting `bsnAPClearConfig` will immediately reboot the LWAP:

  ```
  snmpset -v 2c -OXsq -c private -m AIRESPACE-WIRELESS-MIB <WLC_IP> \
    bsnAPClearConfig.255.254.253.252.251.250 integer 1
  ```
- Assign [bsnAPName (rw)](http://tools.cisco.com/Support/SNMP/do/BrowseOID.do?local=en&translate=Translate&objectInput=1.3.6.1.4.1.14179.2.2.1.1.3#oidContent), [bsnAPPrimaryMwarName (rw)](http://tools.cisco.com/Support/SNMP/do/BrowseOID.do?local=en&translate=Translate&objectInput=1.3.6.1.4.1.14179.2.2.1.1.10#oidContent), [bsnAPSecondaryMwarName (rw)](http://tools.cisco.com/Support/SNMP/do/BrowseOID.do?local=en&translate=Translate&objectInput=1.3.6.1.4.1.14179.2.2.1.1.23#oidContent) using `snmpset`
- Get the [bsnAPSerialNumber (ro)](http://tools.cisco.com/Support/SNMP/do/BrowseOID.do?local=en&translate=Translate&objectInput=1.3.6.1.4.1.14179.2.2.1.1.17#oidContent); save it to a CSV file along with [bsnAPEthernetMacAddress (ro)](http://tools.cisco.com/Support/SNMP/do/BrowseOID.do?local=en&translate=Translate&objectInput=1.3.6.1.4.1.14179.2.2.1.1.33#oidContent), [bsnAPName (rw)](http://tools.cisco.com/Support/SNMP/do/BrowseOID.do?local=en&translate=Translate&objectInput=1.3.6.1.4.1.14179.2.2.1.1.3#oidContent), [bsnAPPrimaryMwarName (rw)](http://tools.cisco.com/Support/SNMP/do/BrowseOID.do?local=en&translate=Translate&objectInput=1.3.6.1.4.1.14179.2.2.1.1.10#oidContent), and [bsnAPSecondaryMwarName (rw)](http://tools.cisco.com/Support/SNMP/do/BrowseOID.do?local=en&translate=Translate&objectInput=1.3.6.1.4.1.14179.2.2.1.1.23#oidContent)
- Reset the LWAP if required with [bsnAPReset (rw)](http://tools.cisco.com/Support/SNMP/do/BrowseOID.do?local=en&translate=Translate&objectInput=1.3.6.1.4.1.14179.2.2.1.1.11#oidContent)

Using SNMP to manage LWAPs has been helpful, since I can automatically react to changes in LWAP to WLC mappings, as well as when an AP drops offline or gets large error / user counts.  I usually poll them all every 15 minutes and record who is on them, as well as recording what LWAPs are on each controller.  The WLC is powerful, but I like building custom-reaction scripts and reports.

Comment: Mike, I can't believe I didn't think of using SNMP for this...  I guess that's tunnel vision for you.  :)  I've previously used SNMP and Perl to pull reporting directly from the controllers, [(via SNMP::info::Airespace)](http://search.cpan.org/dist/SNMP-Info/Info/Airespace.pm), but for some reason I never thought about using SNMP for this.

Comment: I quit using perl several years ago, so I didn't know about the Airespace module, that's a useful pointer